# Word or expression for Undermining your authority by being too strict

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I have the sense that if an authority, be it a person or otherwise (e.g. a parent or some religious text), is extremely strict on some issues, they might come to be seen as unreasonable generally. This would have the effect of undermining their influence on *all* issues, even those for which most people would find their guidance quite prudent.

Is there a word or expression for this situation? It feels similar to "crying wolf." Does that cover it, or is there something more specific?

Edit: forgot an example sentence: I don't have a particular part of speech in mind, so I'll give a few versions.

"Adam had developed a reputation as being obsessed with the rules. As a result, he had become *adjective*, and people tended to disregard his disapproval."

"Adam had developed a reputation as being obsessed with the rules. As a result *verb*, and people tended to disregard his disapproval."

"Adam had developed a reputation as being obsessed with the rules. As a result, people tended to disregard his disapproval. A classic example of *noun/phrase/verb*."

Edit 2: A lot of useful suggestions in the comments that could be applied in situations involving what I'm describing, but none of them seem to be a *general* term/phrase. I suspect there isn't one. What should I do then - just leave the question unanswered?

Comment: @Cascabel Thanks for the reminder about the sentence. I've been away for a little while and forgot. Do elaborating on what your problem is with the "premise" of the question?

Comment: Sounds as though Adam is courting a mutiny! That's what happened to Captain Bligh when he came down too hard on his crew of the H.M.S. Bounty in 1789. Legalism in a leader tends to foment mutiny among his or her crew. A good leader knows when to lighten up a bit. Moreover, a good leader doesn't demand respect but commands respect. As for a word or phrase to summarize the tendency within a leader to stir the pot of mutiny, I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: "obsessive"  seems to relate -- you used that word in an example

Comment: The term "malicious enforcement" comes close.

Comment: Not quite right, but "shooting oneself in the foot" is an approximation of what you want.

Comment: Isn't Adam turning himself into a vestige?

Comment: Your edits make the question much more clear in its intent, but I still do not know if there will be a single word to describe the situation. The comments about "inciting to mutiny" seem promising.

Comment: I would describe Adam as obstinate or pertinacious but, if I've interpreted the question correctly, you're looking for a word to describe this 'undermining'  situation, not just Adam's manner?

Comment: I think you're on a hiding to nothing, Evan. You might well find an expression for either *being too strict* or *undermining your authority* and I don’t think you want to hold your breath waiting for anything even touching on, let alone clearly meaning anything like *both*.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Well at least I learned the expression "on a hiding to nothing."

Comment: Since you noticed it, I actually looked that up for the first time in my life and while I'm not surprised to learn (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hiding_to_nothing) it comes from horse racin, I didn't find it obvious at all…

Comment: I forgot to mention that the *process* in *crying wolf* would seem t fit perfectly… I'm just one of those who thinks it can't be applied here.

There might be a possibility of twisting something out of *his bark was worse than his bite* and again I think the content puts too much strain on the fit of the process.

Comment: "Dogmatic" and "draconian" are just two of a very many words which in various ways indict excessive strictness

Answer (score 2):

Overbearing is "the tendency to overwhelm" and literally to "bear fruit or offspring to excess." MW. A person who is overbearing on one specific issue would likely have a broad negative effect.